# Modelling of two time series data which seem to move together?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, cross-correlation

I have two time series data, these two data when looked at graphically seem to move roughly together i.e. on a higher level the shape of the two is similar. I want to apply some kind of modeling to see if I can predict the direction of one time series using the other, but I think I don't have the necessary skill now. I am aware of univariate time series modeling, I guess it comes under bivariate time series modeling. What topics should I study, to be able to gather some insights from these two time series data?

Comment: Hi: Some terms that come to mind are transfer response function, cross correlation and distributed lags. Hopefully someone else can add some more relevant terms.

Comment: Can you show us a plot of the two time series, and a plot of the cross-correlation function? A lag plot can also be useful.